# Whether Longpress supported in tizen wearable app?

Tags: tizen

I used mousedown and mouseup events to identify long click. But that is not working in Tizen emulator for me. But the same code is working fine in browsers. Tau provided by tizen supports only swipe.

The code below works fine in browsers:

```js
var timeOut;
$("button").mouseup(function(event){
     
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
});
$("button").mousedown(function(event){
    
    timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
        
        alert('you hold your mouse more than 2 seconds.!');
      
    },2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```

[Referred this fiddle too](https://jsfiddle.net/7jKYa/10/)

But nothing works in tizen wearable emulator. So any other suggestion I can try??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'touchstart' and 'touchend' instead of 'mousedown' and 'mouseup'.

I tested below code now with Basic Web Template. It working well! :)

main.js

```
window.onload = function() {
// TODO:: Do your initialization job

// add eventListener for tizenhwkey
document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
    if (e.keyName === "back") {
        try {
            tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
        } catch (ignore) {}
    }
});

// Sample code
var mainPage = document.querySelector('#main');

var timeOut;
var cnt = 0;
mainPage.addEventListener("touchend", function() {
    var contentText = document.querySelector('#content-text');
    console.log("timer clear!");
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
});

mainPage.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    var contentText = document.querySelector('#content-text');
    console.log("touchstart!");
    timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("long!");
        contentText.innerHTML = "Long!" + cnt;
        cnt++;
    },2000);
});
```

};

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer causes long-press events to trigger in some other situations, like when the user was actually scrolling the view for long enough. Also any regular handler (like regular tap)  would still fire on a long-press. This version fixes those issues. Also it will produce the usual feedback (haptic and audio, as configured in the device settings) for a long-press.

```js
var longpressTimer;
var wasLongpress = false;
function endLongpress(e) {
    if (wasLongpress) {
        // Prevent default handling, like taps
        e.preventDefault();
        wasLongpress = false;
    } else if (longpressTimer) {
        clearTimeout(longpressTimer);
        longpressTimer = null;
    }
}

// Could target any other element, like a specific control.
var target = document.getElementById('body');
// Any of these should cancel a long-press, or be canceled if the last touch was the start of a long-press
target.addEventListener("touchcancel", function(e) {
    endLongpress(e);
});

target.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
    endLongpress(e);
});

target.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
    endLongpress(e);
});

target.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    longpressTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        longpressTimer = null;
        e.preventDefault();
        // So that we know we should prevent default handling
        wasLongpress = true;
        try {
            tizen.feedback.play('HOLD');
        } catch (err) {
            //unable to play feedback
        }
        // handle long-press from here
        console.log("long!");
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Though I'm not currently using Tizen, this may help someone..